# spring mvc web app class design

Tags: java, spring-mvc

im implementing web app in java spring mvc. currently my class design is as follows:
- class product
- Interface ProductManager
- class ProductManagerImpl which implements interface Product manager

so basically, class product contains all the member variables, getter and setters. the interface ProductManager contains the business logic methods without implementation. the class ProductmanagerImpl contains the implementation of interface ProductManager.

```
public class Product {
 private String name;
 private String description;
 private int qty;

 getter()..
 setter()..
}

public Interface ProductManager() {
 public List<Product> getProducts();
}

public class ProductManagerImpl implements ProductManager() {
 public List<Product> getProducts() {
  ...

 return products;
 }
}
```

So in my controller, i will call ProductManagerImpl and retrieve the list of products and send to the view.

ok here comes my question(s)..

if the product qty is 0, i will set the color in red.
if the product qty is between 1 and 5, i set to yellow
if the product qty is above 5, it will be set as green

where should i implement the checks? should it be in implementation class? i read in the mvc tutorial that its best not to implement logic in the view file.

Comment: Personally, i will do that check in view, but i don't see reason why you couldn;t do this in controller, your view coulld have additional method for setting colours, or you could add parameter colour to `setProduct` method in your view

Comment: hey im using tiles as my templating framework. so it will contain jstl. how can i implement methods in the view?

Comment: as far as i remember, you can have if-else statements in jstl

Comment: thing im bothered about is i have to hardcode static value for comparison

Comment: you could pass those values as well, but then your page might look as big mess, try to do this in controller then, and pass colour value

Comment: I would write a JSTL expression, it is view related and not business. So do it on the client. Something like this should work `style="${product.qty == 0 ? 'color: red' : product.qty > 5 ? 'color: green' : color: 'yellow'}"` or use a switch/case statement...